# What is the exact name of this keyboard shortcut in Visual Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Code, the combination `fn+alt+N` (Mac keys) is a keyboard shortcut that triggers a "duplicate view" of the currently viewed file.

So far I was unable to find the command's exact name in the long list of keyboard shortcuts in Keyboard Preferences, and I need that in order to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the key bind GUI (command **Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts**)

Do one of the following:

1. enable the **Record Keys** button (in the input box) and then type your key binding
2. with **Record Keys** button disabled type `duplicate` or some other part of the command name found in the Command Palette